# Using R or Excel to match strings

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I  have an Excel Sheet with two columns. Column A is 1000 strings. Column C has 300 strings (a subset of the 1000 strings in Column A).

I need to determine whether not each string in Column A is in Column C, perhaps assign it a value of 1 if it is, and 0 if it is not.

Is there an if statement in Excel to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following formula should do the trick:

```
  =IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,C:C,1,0))),1,0)
```

Comment: This can be simplified to `=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,C:C,1,0)),0,1)`

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the following formula (using the match function)

The third argument in the match function, 0, tells it you are looking for an exact match.

```
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,$C$1:$C$300,0))),1,0)
```